# How to link a Sass file in a Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sass

I am trying to link a Sass file to a Sinatra app. I have a `public/sass/styles.scss` file and I am trying to link it in my `views/layout.haml` file. I am able to link a regular css file using the following link in my `layout.haml`: `%link(rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css")`. However, when I try and link to my `sass/styles.scss`, it does not work. Can someone please tell me how to link a Sass css file in a Sinatra app? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont link the scss, a scss like a sass is not a file that is supposed to be interpreted by the browser, you need a compiler that process this file and convert it to css.

You need the compass gem to automatically generate the css from your scss and then you link the css as you were referring before

Here you have an example of compass configuration for sinatra:

> https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/wiki/Sinatra-Integration

Comment: He doesn't need a separate gem for compiling scss since Sass has that built in. Compass looks really interesting though.

Comment: That link says "If you keep your stylesheets in "views/stylesheets/" directory instead of just "views/", remember to update `sass_dir` configuration accordingly." what exactly does that mean? the `sass_dir` part

Answer (score 51):

You can use [Sass::Plugin::Rack](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Plugin/Rack.html)

First install the Sass gem.

Add it in your Gemfile, if you are using Bundler: `gem 'sass'`.

In your `config.ru` add:

```
require 'sass/plugin/rack'

Sass::Plugin.options[:style] = :compressed
use Sass::Plugin::Rack
```

Then create a folder in `public/stylesheets/sass/`, and drop all your .scss and .sass files there.

This will create the corresponding .css in `public/stylesheets/`

For example: `public/stylesheets/sass/style.scss` will generate `public/stylesheets/style.css`

And that's it, you can change the paths from the default ones and change other options mentioned in the [reference docs](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options)

Comment: not sure why you're not getting any love here - this worked great and seems a lot cleaner

Comment: @Mojowen it's probably cause the question is fairly old and the answer is kinda new. Thanks for the upvote, I also find this is a simpler/cleaner way!

Comment: no doubt this is the best answer, since I don't want to use compass

Comment: Note that this won't work if you start the app in dev with `ruby myapp.rb`, since that ignores `config.ru`. Instead start the app with something like `rackup`.

Answer (score 16):

You don't need to use a separate gem to compile your .scss files, Sass has that built-in.

`sass --watch style.scss:style.css` will set Sass to automatically compile style.scss into style.css whenever it gets changed. From the [Sass website](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html),

> Now whenever you change style.scss, Sass will automatically update style.css with the changes. Later on when you have several Sass files, you can also watch an entire directory

Answer (score 14):

You could do:

```
get '/stylesheets/*.css' do
  content_type 'text/css', :charset => 'utf-8'
  filename = params[:splat].first
  sass filename.to_sym, :views => "#{settings.root}/assets/stylesheets"
end
```